# JavaScript Validation when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript

See my codes below regarding a quiz question. I want to have a function when I missed a radio button (s), an alert box should popped displaying the number of questions I missed when I clicked the "Grade Me" button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = "quiz.js"> </script>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "quiz_style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
       <center><h1> &copy; JavaScript Quiz by Hamsheed ! :) </h1></center> 
        <div id = "wrapper">
        <form id = "quiz">
            <fieldset>
                <legend> Question 1 </legend>
                He _____ it. <br>
                <label><input type = "radio" value = "wrong" name = "q1" id = "q"> don't like <br></label>
                <label><input type = "radio" value = "right" name = "q1" id = "q"> doesn't like <br></label>
                <label><input type = "radio" value = "wrong" name = "q1" id = "q"> don't likes <br></label>
            </fieldset> <br>

            <fieldset>
                <legend> Question 2 </legend>
                They _____ here very often. <br>
                <label><input type = "radio" value = "right" name = "q2" id = "q"> don't come <br></label>
                <label><input type = "radio" value = "wrong" name = "q2" id = "q"> doesn't comes <br></label>
                <label><input type = "radio" value = "wrong" name = "q2" id = "q"> doesn't coming <br></label>
            </fieldset> <br>

            <fieldset>
                <legend> Question 3 </legend>
                John and Mary _____ twice last week. <br>
                <label><input type = "radio" value = "wrong" name = "q3"> comes <br></label>
                <label><input type = "radio" value = "right" name = "q3"> came <br></label>
                <label><input type = "radio" value = "wrong" name = "q3"> coming <br></label>
            </fieldset> <br>
```

```
 var score = 0;
function validate(){               
 var rad = document.getElementById("quiz").getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++){
     if (rad[i].checked == true && rad[i].value == "right") {
        score++; 
    } 

    }

         var pcnt = ((score/10) * 100);
     alert("The score is " + score + " and percentage is " + pcnt + " %" );
    }
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that what code that should I write to get an alert box if I miss one or two questions? It should displays the number of questions I have missed too.

Comment: So count the number of checked radio buttons, and deal with the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <script>
 var score = 0;
function validate(){               
 var rad = document.getElementById("quiz").getElementsByTagName('input');
    attend = 0
    for(var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++){
      if (rad[i].checked == true){ attend = attend +1}
     if (rad[i].checked == true && rad[i].value == "right") {
        score++; 
    } 

    }

         var pcnt = ((score/10) * 100);
     alert("The score is " + score + " and percentage is " + pcnt + " %" + "\n"+
      "not_attend: " + Math.floor((rad.length-(3*attend))/3) );
    }
         </script>
```

Comment: here `not_attend` gives number of not attend set of radio inputs.So we can divide by 3 since you have 3 options.

Comment: It does not work.. Do you have other means to do it ?

Comment: Yes ! My score is working perfectly.. 

I want an alert to pop up whenever I leave out any blank asnwers.. The alert box should displays the number of questions that I left blank.. Hope its clear now :) Thanks

Comment: Works like charm :D 
Thank you ! 
Why can't I vote your answer ? :/ 
I dont have enough reputation to do so :/

Comment: Why did you set the rad[i].checked == true ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some framework like jquery which turns complext things little bit easy. try like  following.

```js
$(function(){
  var lastTraversed;
  $('#sendbtn').click(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)').each(function(a){
      if(!$("input:radio[name='"+this.name+"']").is(":checked") && lastTraversed !== this.name)
        {
         lastTraversed = this.name;
         alert(this.name);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = "quiz.js"> </script>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "quiz_style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
       <center><h1> &copy; JavaScript Quiz by Hamsheed ! :) </h1></center> 
        <div id = "wrapper">
        <form id = "quiz">
            <fieldset>
                <legend> Question 1 </legend>
                He _____ it. <br>
                <label><input type = "radio" value = "wrong" name = "q1" id = "q"> don't like <br></label>
                <label><input type = "radio" value = "right" name = "q1" id = "q"> doesn't like <br></label>
                <label><input type = "radio" value = "wrong" name = "q1" id = "q"> don't likes <br></label>
            </fieldset> <br>

            <fieldset>
                <legend> Question 2 </legend>
                They _____ here very often. <br>
                <label><input type = "radio" value = "right" name = "q2" id = "q"> don't come <br></label>
                <label><input type = "radio" value = "wrong" name = "q2" id = "q"> doesn't comes <br></label>
                <label><input type = "radio" value = "wrong" name = "q2" id = "q"> doesn't coming <br></label>
            </fieldset> <br>

            <fieldset>
                <legend> Question 3 </legend>
                John and Mary _____ twice last week. <br>
                <label><input type = "radio" value = "wrong" name = "q3"> comes <br></label>
                <label><input type = "radio" value = "right" name = "q3"> came <br></label>
                <label><input type = "radio" value = "wrong" name = "q3"> coming <br></label>
            </fieldset> <br>
          <input id="sendbtn" type="button" value="send" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But do you have other means to do this without jQuery? 
I mean using only JavaScript !

Comment: @user3545953 Without jquery it would be very tedious coding..! Why you don't want to go with jquery? Any specific reason?

Comment: I have not learnt jQuery yet :p 
I want to have a good grasp of JavaScript first.. Then I'll move on with the tutorials for JQuery :D